# Warning: unknown QT: bluetooth

Tags: qt, ubuntu, bluetooth, warnings

I'm running Ubuntu and Qt 5. When I add `QT += bluetooth` to the .pro file it tells me "Warning: unknown QT: bluetooth". I HAVE INSTALLED qtconnectivity5-dev. I have been facing this problem for like 4 hours now.

Comment: Installing the package `qtconnectivity5-dev` is not the usual way Qt devs install the environment. Follow this: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu At least on a couple of Linux machines I use I never needed anything besides prebuilt Qt installed normal way and my projects to use Bluetooth. I cannot put this as an answer yet, though, because dev package should have some use. But if the way I described works for you I can elaborate in an actual answer. Who knows why the package Qt was built without Bluetooth?

Comment: I reintalled Qt and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Qt helped. Dont know what the problem was, but it was solved